# Pass Firebase Data from TableViewCell to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying multiple ways to pass my firebase data from a TableViewCell to a ViewController and can't figure out the simplest solution.

I have an EncounterTableViewController with EncounterTableViewCells.  This is populated with Firebase data.  When an EncounterTableViewCell is selected I want to pass the data to the EncounterDetailViewController.

EncountersTableViewController.swift

```
class EncountersTableViewController: UITableViewController  {

    var encounters : [Encounter] = []

    // MARK: - View Did load
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       showAllEncounters()
    }

    // MARK: - Encounter filters
    func showAllEncounters() {
        // Firebase tableview data
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("encounters").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {

            guard let restDict = rest.value as? [String: Any] else { continue }

            let encounter = Encounter()
            encounter.sharkName = (restDict["shark_name"] as? String)!
            encounter.date = (restDict["trip_date"] as? String)!
            encounter.contributorName = (restDict["contributor"] as? String)!
            encounter.contributorImage = (restDict["contributor_image"] as? String)!


            let mediaDict = (restDict["media"] as? NSArray)
            let firstImage = mediaDict![0] as! NSDictionary
            encounter.mainImage = firstImage["thumb_url"] as! String

            self.encounters.append(encounter)

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
      })
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segueToEncounterCard" {
            let destination = segue.destination as! EncounterDetailViewController
        }
    }
```

EncounterDetailViewController.swift

```
class EncounterDetailViewController: UIViewController {

// MARK: - Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var encounterDateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var locationLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lengthLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var contributorNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var contributorImageView: UIImageView!

// MARK: - Properties
var dictionary: [String:AnyObject]?

// MARK: - View did load
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
}
```

Comment: Is segue connected from UItableViewCell to destinationController ?

Comment: How are you navigating from `EncountersTableViewController` to `EncounterDetailViewController`?

Comment: The segue is connected from the EncounterTableViewCell to the EncounterDetailViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing `dictionary` you need to pass object of `Encounter`, so declare one instance property of type `Encounter` in your `EncounterDetailViewController` with named `selectedEncounter`. Now in `prepareForSegue` method of `EncountersTableViewController` pass the object of `Encounter` from array to this `detailViewController.`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueToEncounterCard" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! EncounterDetailViewController
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            destination.selectedEncounter = self.encounters[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

**EncounterDetailViewController**

```
class EncounterDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var encounterDateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lengthLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var contributorNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var contributorImageView: UIImageView!

    // MARK: - Properties
    var selectedEncounter: Encounter?

    // MARK: - View did load
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //access selectedEncounter property here and set all label's text
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh thanks for the info @Nirav!  Was trying to access the dictionary info.  Knew there had to be a more simple way.

Comment: @pmanning Welcome mate :), One more thing that I forgot to tell is that don't use `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` in Swift use native type array and dictionary means you can retrieve media array like this `restDict["media"] as! [[String:Any]]` now no need to cast to first object to dictionary because we array specify array as array of dictionary.

Comment: Thanks @Nirav actually helps with my next task of retrieving some nested data :)

Answer (score 0):

In EncountersTableViewController add the tableView delegate method, `func tableView(UITableView, didSelectRowAt: IndexPath)` and inside this method, you can get the selected encounter from encounter array by using indexPath.row. After you get the encounter you can `performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToEncounterCard" , sender: encounter )`.

And in prepareForSegue method, you can get the encounter by casting sender value as Encounter object and you can pass the encounter to destination.